# SSH operation timed out / cannot login with SSH until local logon has been completed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, login, openssh

Having an issue using SSH, I attempt to log in to my server using SSH and have no issues if an account is locally logged in. However if an account is not logged into locally I get an error that says "operation timed out". After some research people suggested to move the authorized_keys file and I tried that using the permissions suggested by that user. However this issue still persists. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Output of `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

Mar 26 11:39:47 cname pkexec[2577]: uname: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/unname] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/cpufreqctl on 1]
Mar 26 11:39:47 cname pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 26 11:39:47 cname pkexec[2584]: uname: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/uname] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/cpufreqctl on 2]
Mar 26 11:39:47 cname pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 26 11:39:47 cname pkexec[2591]: uname: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/uname] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/cpufreqctl on 3]
Mar 26 11:40:10 cname dbus-daemon[861]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Mar 26 11:41:15 cname sshd[2911]: Connection closed by authenticating user uname 10.0.1.8 port 50209 [preauth]
Mar 26 11:41:31 cname sshd[2942]: Accepted publickey for uname from 10.0.1.8 port 50212 ssh2: RSA SHA256:Ae/Ak3P6EaQ/iGY4ZkZ6hXemzUWY+UDJ2uyAZggZ4gk
Mar 26 11:41:31 cname sshd[2942]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user uname by (uid=0)
Mar 26 11:41:31 cname systemd-logind[895]: New session 4 of user uname.

Output of `journalctl -u ssh -ef`

-- Reboot --
Mar 26 11:38:43 cname systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mar 26 11:38:43 cname sshd[988]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34.
Mar 26 11:38:43 cname sshd[988]: Server listening on :: port 34.
Mar 26 11:38:43 cname systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname sshd[988]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname sshd[988]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname sshd[988]: Server listening on :: port 34.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname sshd[988]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname sshd[988]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34.
Mar 26 11:39:44 cname sshd[988]: Server listening on :: port 34.
Mar 26 11:41:15 cname sshd[2911]: Connection closed by authenticating user uname 10.0.1.8 port 50209 [preauth]
Mar 26 11:41:31 cname sshd[2942]: Accepted publickey for uname from 10.0.1.8 port 50212 ssh2: RSA SHA256:Ae/Ak3P6EaQ/iGY4ZkZ6hXemzUWY+UDJ2uyAZggZ4gk
Mar 26 11:41:31 cname sshd[2942]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user uname by (uid=0)
Mar 26 12:51:54 cname sshd[988]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Mar 26 12:51:54 cname systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mar 26 12:51:54 cname systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Reboot --
Mar 26 12:52:14 cname systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mar 26 12:52:14 cname sshd[981]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34.
Mar 26 12:52:14 cname sshd[981]: Server listening on :: port 34.
Mar 26 12:52:14 cname systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname sshd[981]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname sshd[981]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname sshd[981]: Server listening on :: port 34.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname sshd[981]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname sshd[981]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname sshd[981]: Server listening on :: port 34.
Mar 26 12:55:41 cname systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have per-user encryption, or EncryptedHome?  If so, the [EncryptedHome documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) describes working around issues with `ssh`.

By default, `sshd` looks in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  If your directory is encrypted, this file is not available.  To solve this problem, you can store each user's `authorized_keys` files outside of their encrypted, home directory, which is controlled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Changes to this configuration file are not seen until `sshd` restarts, ie: `$ sudo systemctl restart sshd` .

Be sure to check out that documentation for all available solutions, and take notice how `cron` can have issues as well.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear when I was talking about the authorized_key folder. I did indeed follow the steps you outlined also verified the permissions of the folder once moved to the /etc/ssh/uname. When you had mentioned cron are you referring to using cron to start the ssh service ?

Comment: `cron` is unrelated to your `ssh` issue.  Just wanted to mention that it falls under similar issues with EncryptedHome.  After you restart `sshd`, have you taken a look at logs provided?  Could you update your question with some logs/errors?  `journalctl -u sshd -ef` or `tail -f /var/log/auth.log`. This will show the 'server' errors, vs the 'client' error "Operation Timed Out" that you see in your terminal.

Comment: Added requested log files